# php array data sorting

Tags: php, arrays

Have troubles with sorting data in array, after I loop through a table in my database these are result:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [model] => Cars
            [number] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [model] => Cars
            [number] => 113
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [model] => Train
            [number] => 220
        )
)
```

From data above, how do I get them to be like below?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cars
    (
        [0] => 101
        [1] => 113
    )
    [2] => Train
    (
        [0] => 220
    )
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi nway, Cars(..) is object? If yes then it's a bit difficult!

Comment: Else, You can put any item in associative array like `Array('Cars'=>Array(101,102),..)`

Comment: Now I know, did not think of that. @Eddie wrote perfect solution. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if cars,trains ... are in a column in your table you can use `GROUP BY` to get data from database and then use it like that array you want.
if not use this loop :

```
$array; //your array
$new_array=[];
foreach($array as $i => $item){
   if(!array_key_exists($item[model],$new_array))
       $new_array[$item[model]]=[];

    $new_array[$item[model]][]=$item[number];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce` to group your array.

Note: I used `model` as the key of the `$result`

```
$arr = //your array
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $o){
    $c[$o['model']][] = $o['number'];
    return $c;
},array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [Cars] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
            [1] => 113
        )

    [Train] => Array
        (
            [0] => 220
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)